# Two part form on single page in django

Tags: python, django, forms, python-3.4

How would I go about making a two part form on a single page? As in the form would have different tabs to switch between different views of the the form all while on the same page? could this be done with AJAX?

I'm using Django and python 3.4 currently.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm6OG.png)

Comment: you just use two form in one view. Did you use CBV?

Comment: @seuling Not at the moment. I currently use FV. I thought about doing it that way (two forms in one view). I just couldn't figure out how to do it. I'm still learning by the way.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Thanks for the help @seuling.

Comment: ok good news! If something wrong, just ask anytime!